# How to deploy process in processmaker UAT server

Tags: processmaker

What is deployment process for created process on UAT server for testing in processmaker. I am using Processmaker 3.0

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. Follow the step.
1.Export your process and PM tables(if any) of that process.
2.Import that process on UAT server.
3.Go to admin panel-> PM table-> Import PM tables.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying processes in ProcessMaker from Development Server to UAT server is very easy.

You must have the role of System Administrator or just a permission of PM_FACTORY, then you will be seeing the dashboard called "Designer". Once you are in designer, you must click the checkbox on the left side on the corresponding project you need to export and then click Export (it will download you a .pmx file). You will import it in your UAT and viola. It's Done.

PM-Tables too must be downloaded because they might be used as a query for dropdowns and values in the process. For more reference, 
[here is a more detailed way to import and export processes](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Importing_and_Exporting_Projects)